# Why my Appliaction using these informations?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

I/PlayCore: UID: [10157]  PID: [1994] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.#####.###)
I/PlayCore: UID: [10157]  PID: [1994] AppUpdateListenerRegistry : registerListener
I/PlayCore: UID: [10157]  PID: [1994] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore: UID: [10157]  PID: [1994] AppUpdateService : Failed to bind to the service.
W/Parcel: Expecting binder but got null!
**D/AutofillManager: Fill dialog is enabled:false, hints=[password, passwordAuto, creditCardNumber, creditCardSecurityCode, creditCardExpirationDate]**
W/System: A resource failed to call close.

> My app - simple offline qr code scanner
> Why are showing these information - **password, passwordAuto, creditCardNumber, creditCardSecurityCode, creditCardExpirationDate**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these links will help you. But from what I can see, just remove hits for the fields you don't need any.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService